# Product ID shown in product page

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'd like to use Product ID instead of Reference Code on product page.

I want to show it like this : **Product ID :** ***Product ID itself***

Example : Product ID of the item in backofice is 47. So that on the product page of this product is shown - **ID :** ***47***   instead of ***Reference Code : dj-fr586***

Comment: I didn't tried anything, cos I'm just "user" not programmer

Comment: Well then we are not able to help you here, we do not just write code for people. We help people with issue's they are experiencing

Answer (score 3):

Go to `themes/yourtheme/product.tpl`. Go to line 118 or search for `id="product_reference"`

Comment out product reference (recommended way instead of removing) by typing

`{* <p id="product_reference" ... </p> *}` aroung `p` tags.

Then insert above:

```
<p id="product_id">
    <label>{l s='Product ID:'} </label>
    <span>{$product->id}</span>
</p>
```

Comment: If `{$product->id}` doesn't work, use `{$product.id_product|intval}`